# Convert an ascii character to ascii hexadecimal representation

Tags: awk

How do I convert an ASCII char to ASCII HEX in a AWK script?

I want loop by a range of letter

example

```
for(i="a"; i<"g"; i++)
 print i;
```

NOTE: I want loop by a range from hex representation and print the character.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you don't really need *all* the characters...

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { chartable="abcdefghij" ; for (i=index(chartable, "a"); i<index(chartable, "g"); i++) { print substr(chartable, i, 1) } }'
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a table containing all the ASCII characters and use the awk builtin `index()` to lookup characters in the table.  Then use `sprintf()` to convert the decimal value returned by `index()` to hex.

```
BEGIN {
    for (i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
       table = sprintf("%s%c", table, i);
    }
}

function chartohex (char) {
    return sprintf("0x%x", index(table, char));
}

END { # examples
   print chartohex("a");
   print chartohex("A");
   print chartohex("!");
}
```

Put this code in the file "foo" and run `awk -f foo < /dev/null` and you'll see the ASCII values for "a", "A" and "!" printed in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

awk does not have ord(), chr() functions like python.
you have to first make array in BEGIN block which index is ascii character and value is decimal number.

```
awk 'BEGIN {
 for (i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
    t = sprintf("%c", i)
    a[t] = i
}

for( i=a["a"]; i < a["g"]; i++)
    print sprintf("%c",i)
}'
a
b
c
d
e
f
```